# Could not identify existing codebase is options api or composition api

Tags: vue.js

I am new to vue js, i was from angular...

From what i read, vue js has two way of writing, options API vs composition API.

**Options API** has something like:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    };
  }
});
</script>
```

Where **Composition API** has the format of:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { ref, defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  setup: () => {
    const count = ref(0);

    return { count };
  },
});
</script>
```

But when i read the existing code base, i can't really know which type of codebase is this? What is the difference?

We use micro frontend as we are small part of entire webpage.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'XXXXX';
import { BannerType, showBanner } XXXXX';
import { itemService} from 'XXXXX';

@Component
export default class UploadItemModal extends Vue {
  @Ref('form')
  readonly form!: InstanceType<typeof ValidationObserver>;

  private isUploading = false;

  private showUploadError = '';

  private showProgressbar = false;

  uploadFieldName = '';

  fileCount = 0;

  fileSize = '';

  selectedFile: File = new File([], '');

  uploading = {
    loaded: 0,
    total: 1,
  };

  private closeDialog(): void {
    //implementation hidden
  }

  private clearData(): void {
    //implementation hidden
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That's class-based syntax, using `vue-class-component`, which is a high-level abstraction of the Options API, which is an abstraction of the Composition API. Use any API that suits your coding preference (and your team's). However, I don't think `vue-class-component` is maintained any longer, so consider switching.

Comment: In terms of TS support, options < classes < composition.